# Why Minimum circuit size problem is important?

Tags: complexity-theory

Given a truth table, find the smallest size circuit computing it. Recently it was shown that for multiple output function the problem MSCP (Minimum Size Circuit Problem) is NP-Complete. The article is available online [see](https://eccc.weizmann.ac.il/report/2020/021/).

**Question:** What will be the impact of this problem? or I am not able to follow why this problem MSCP is so important?

I didn't read the article completely, only the introduction part, it seem to me that problem is related to many other problems of interest.

Comment: From the introduction: "Boolean circuit minimization is of high practical relevance,
and a number of textbooks and monographs have been written about heuristics and other applied aspects of this problem (cf. [McC65, Sch01, HS06])." Did you try to follow these references to see why the problem is of practical interest? Also, the footnote gives different names for the same problem which you can use to look up information on Wikipedia like [logic synthesis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logic_synthesis). The very first sentence of the abstract gives you a clear hint as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Finding the *minimum* size circuit is not important in practice for large circuits. Finding *small* size circuits is of course important because it directly impacts the cost of building a circuit.

Finding minimum size circuits for small circuits that are used as building blocks is quite important. For example, you'd want to know how to build the smallest possible full adder if you end up having a million of them in a processor. And you really want a minimum size circuit for a bit of memory in your L3 cache when your processor has 36MB of L3 cache or 288 million of these cells.

However, minimising the delay of a circuit is also important, and sometimes more important or even far more important than minimum size.

Answer (score 4):

## Meta Complexity

MCSP is one of the two signature problems in the subfield of [meta-complexity](https://iacr.org/submit/files/slides/2022/tcc/tcc2022/0815/slides.pdf). You could say that meta-complexity itself is on the bleeding edge of the P=NP problem. Since the full problem is so difficult to resolve, we are forced to attack it from many angles. Impagliazzo described [5 Worlds](https://stuff.mit.edu/afs/sipb/project/reading-group/past-readings/2009-06-08-five-worlds.pdf) of complexity relative to the P=NP question. MCSP may help eliminate one or more of these worlds from possibility, getting us a little closer to the final result.

I don't think MCSP as studied by complexity researchers has anything to do with real-world circuit optimization, because there are many other considerations when designing real circuits that are completely ignored by MCSP. The most trivial example is that theoretical circuits do not need to concern themselves with fan-in and fan-out, while real circuits do, as this can affect the voltage and current within the circuit at extreme levels.